# Switch functions between files in C

Tags: c, include

Hey there I tried to use functions of another file, this is not a problem, but if I want to use a function of the other file also, i get a problem:

**test1.c**

```
#include "test2.c"

int func1(int a, int b){
    return func2(a, b);
}
```

**test2.c**

```
#include "test1.c"

int func2(int a, int b){
     return a + b;
}

int main(void){
     func1(10, 5);
}
```

this works, but if i get an error, there are pages of the include statements. Have anyone an Idea how to solve this?

Comment: You need two header files - one as test1.h and other as test2.h. Define prototypes of these functions in header files. Include header files instead of source files (.c).

Comment: Just to clarify the previous comment: The prototype declarations that you require are the following: In `test1.h`: `int func1(int a, int b);` In `test2.h`: `int func2(int a, int b);`. That is all that is required in the two header files, but you may want to add an [include guard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) in both files.

Comment: As a rule, you should avoid including `.c` files.  Instead, compile and link your `.c` files.  Declare the external objects in corresponding `.h`. files, and only include the `.h` files.  That way you won't replicate the code, but only the declarations.

Answer (score 1):

In general you should not include C source files in other C source files.
In your specific case, you created a dependency cycle:
test1.c includes test2.c, which includes test1.c again, which includes test2.c ...
Instead, declare function prototypes in header files and include those:

test1.h:

```
#ifndef TEST1_H
#define TEST1_H
int func2(int a, int b);
#endif
```

test2.h

```
#ifndef TEST2_H
#define TEST2_H
int func2(int a, int b);
#endif
```

Now you can include `test2.h` in `test1.c` and `test1.h` in `test2.c`.
Alternatively you can declare a prototype of `func1` in `test2.c` and vice versa, but using header files is the cleaner solution in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

In `test1.c` you need to define the functions you are using that are not in the file <sup>(*)</sup>.

There are two ways:

- you type the prototypes of the functions at the top of your C file
- you provide a header file that contains the prototypes.

Examples:

test1.c

```
int func2(int a, int b);   // you provide a prototype

....
```

Or:

```
#include "test2.h"
```

with test2.h file being:

```
int func2(int a, int b);   // prototype of functions in test2.c
```

<sup>(*) ..or that will be used before defined in the file</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The files `test1.c` and `test2.c` recursively include each other.

You need to place common declarations (especially declarations with external linkage) in a header file.

So create a header where place the function declarations something like

**test.h**

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

int func1(int a, int b);
int func2(int a, int b);

#endif
```

Then create the file `test1.c`

**test1.c**

```
#include "test.h"

int func1(int a, int b){
    return func2(a, b);
}
```

And the file `test2.c` will look like

**test2.c**

```
#include "test.h"

int func2(int a, int b){
     return a + b;
}

int main(void){
     func1(10, 5);
}
```

Though the definition of the function `func2` also could be placed in a separate `.c` file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a header file for example **functions.h**

In the header file you need to write the funcion name found in the **test1.c** and **test2.c** file

**functions.h**

```
#ifdef FUNCTIONS_H
#define FUNCTIONS_H
int func1(int a, int b);
int func2(int a, int b);
#endif
```

In the **test1.c** file you need to include **functions.h**

**test1.c**

```
#include "functions.h"
int func1(int a, int b){
return func2(a, b);
}
```

In the **test2.c** file you need to include **functions.h** as well.

**test2.c**

```
#include "functions.h"
int fun2(int a, int b){
    return a + b;
}
int main(){
    func1(10, 5);
}
```